# Receive Uart Problem with IDLE state STM32

Tags: stm32, uart, dma

I am using Uart1 to serial write function. And I want to use this uart1 interface for the receive unknown length data.
If I do not use the serial write function, I get data correctly (with check LINE idle and count DMA buffer size)

But If I use the serial write function line couldnt be idle on correct time, If I want to print getting data with serial write `uartIdleStateActive2` flag is always ENABLE

How can I use this      `if((__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1, UART_FLAG_IDLE) != RESET))`  case, only receive proccess.

I am using like theese       `if((__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1, UART_FLAG_IDLE) != RESET) && (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1, UART_FLAG_TC) != SET))`     but it didnt work. How can I check it to look at the idle state at receive time?

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 0 */
  /* UART IDLE Interrupt */
//   SerialPrint("a");
  if((__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1, UART_FLAG_IDLE) != RESET))  
  {   
    HAL_UART_DMAStop(&huart1);
    DMA_CounterCounted2 =  __HAL_DMA_GET_COUNTER(huart1.hdmarx);

    if(((DMA_CounterCounted2) <= DMA_BUF_SIZE) && (DMA_CounterCounted2 != 0))
    {
     uartIdleStateActive2 = (_Bool)ENABLE;

//      SerialPrint("X");
    }
 
    __HAL_UART_CLEAR_IDLEFLAG(&huart1);
  }
  

  /* USER CODE END USART2_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_IRQn 1 */
}
```

UART 1 configurations:

```
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 230400U;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */
  __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_IDLE);
//   __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_RXNE);

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}
```

Comment: There is an interrupt for IDLE flag, do you have it enabled? `__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_IDLE)`

Comment: Yes, I enabled. When I use the serial write function for the write getting value; uartIdleStateActive2 flag always enable, I dont know why ?

Comment: I also added Uart1 configurations